# How do I pass an argument to the Success Function of a Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got an Ajax.ActionLink like so:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Load Related Titles",
"AjaxLoadRelated",
"Shared",
new { RelatedComics = c.RelatedComic.RelatedTitles },
new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "divRelatedTitles", LoadingElementId = "divLoading", OnBegin = "ajaxLoadMoreBegin", OnFailure = "ajaxLoadMoreFailed", OnSuccess = "ajaxLoadMoreSuccess" })
```

Currently my OnSuccess function looks like so:

```
function ajaxLoadMoreSuccess() {
    ...
}
```

I would like to pass an argument to it:

```
function ajaxLoadMoreSuccess(myArg) {
    ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to do. The mvc ajax unobtrusive script creates an anonymous function
with three parameters(corresponding to the parameters for the jquery ajax complete method)
data, status, xhr and calling that method with the arguments for the jquery ajax complete method. So for example:

`...OnSuccess = "ajaxLoadMoreSuccess1('hello world')"`

Or

`...OnSuccess = "ajaxLoadMoreSuccess2(calc(), data, status, xhr)"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxLoadMoreSuccess1(message) {
        alert(message);
    }

    function ajaxLoadMoreSuccess2(x, data, status, xhr) {
        $('#somespan').text('calc was ' + x + ' and data is ' + data);
    }

    function calc() {
        return 1 + 2;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't figure that out for myself! Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm trying to pass `this` (the generated anchor itself).

Comment: That's because the `this` pointer is not bound to the dom element for the anonymous function or for the `ajaxLoadMoreSuccess` function. So `ajaxLoadMoreSuccess(this)`, here `this` is the same `this` as for the ajax success call(see [`context` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). And inside `ajaxLoadMoreSuccess` function `this` is bound to the global object(`window`). You can tweak the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js script so it's binding `this` to the dom element. But more easily, set an id on the `a` tag and use jquery to get the element. Like this, `ajaxLoadMoreSuccess($('#my-a-id'))`.